# Best Practices for Independent Python Git Submodules for Installation

Tags: python, git, installation, microservices, git-submodules

I am working on a huge Python Project with multiple Python repositories that I am importing into my main project using Git Submodules. The main problem isn't the submodule, but how to import each git repo.

Each repo has a "setup.py" which you can simply run "python setup.py install". To do this for the repo, I just go into each repo and run this for each repo I want to import. I can also make a easy bash script to install the dependencies easily, but I was wondering if someone had a better easier way. I am just asking this kind of question in order to become a better developer with better practices in a structured way.

I have tried googling around, but nothing is really concrete on what's the best way or I just find anything that is really related to my problem.

Also I want the packages I have to be private so I am not sure if making pip packages are the way to go.

I don't want to make one huge git repo as I want everything to be a stand-alone application if needed to be.

If anyone could give any good advice or a good direction in there experience with these kind of development problem that would be nice. If what I'm doing is clearly bad Python Project management, I would like just a blunt answer as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: interested in other views as well for this kind of issue. I had a different yet similar issue with a big project, I ended up adding a makefile to the root of the project handling all the setup tasks.